# How to determine whether LinearLayout is too small to contain its children

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-viewgroup

When a `LinearLayout` has its height set to `wrap_content` and its children have a combined height larger than the screen, some children will not be visible. In that case, I want to remove children until all children are visible. What is an efficient way to do this?

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    //when measuring with unspecified, the layout will be as large as it wants to be
    super.onMeasure(UNSPECIFIED_SPEC, UNSPECIFIED_SPEC);
    if (getOrientation() == VERTICAL){
        wantedLength = getMeasuredHeight();

    } else {
        wantedLength = getMeasuredWidth();
    }

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    if (getOrientation() == VERTICAL){
        measuredLength = getMeasuredHeight();

    } else {
        measuredLength = getMeasuredWidth();
    }


    while (measuredLength < wantedLength){
        //todo remove child
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        if (getOrientation() == VERTICAL){
            measuredLength = getMeasuredHeight();

        } else {
            measuredLength = getMeasuredWidth();
        }
    }

}
```

Is there a way to know whether the layout is too small without measuring twice? I found `MEASURED_STATE_TOO_SMALL` in the docs but don't know how to use it.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getMeasuredHeightAndState()

Comment: why not use `scrollview` to hold all? anyway to can get display size from `Display` class. Then calculate total sizes of your items. then remove the other items.

Comment: I want to present information in 1 screen without scrolling. When children don't fit, less important ones can be removed

Answer (score 0):

Get the display size in pixel

```
public Map<String, Integer> deriveMetrics(Activity activity) {
    try {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();

        if (activity != null) {
            activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        }

        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        map.put("screenWidth", Integer.valueOf(metrics.widthPixels));
        map.put("screenHeight", Integer.valueOf(metrics.heightPixels));
        map.put("screenDensity", Integer.valueOf(metrics.densityDpi));

        return map;
    } catch (Exception err) {
        ; // just use zero values
        return null;
    }
}
```

> Then You can get the views parent by calling viewName.getParent() and
>   with getWidth() and getHeight() you get the pixel you need.
>
> Then do your calculation which one to keep and which one to remove.